# Mutt | SMTP session failed: 553 5.7.1

Tags: mutt, smtp

I'm trying to set-up my aol mail to work with mutt. I can read my messeges but can't send/reply. All I get is this message:

> SMTP session failed: 553 5.7.1 : Sender
>   address rejected: not owned by user sebastiansalamanca Could not send
>   the message.

I've set-up the smtp with the right port, user and password . I don't get what's going on.

thanks in advance

my .muttrc file

```
set ssl_starttls=yes
set ssl_force_tls=yes

set imap_user = "my.mail@aol.com"
set imap_pass = "xxxxxx"

set smtp_url = "smtp://my.mail@smtp.aol.com:587/"
set smtp_pass = "xxxxxx"

set folder = "imaps://imap.aol.com:993"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
set use_from=yes

set from = "my.mail@aol.com"
set realname = "Sebastian Salamanca"

set header_cache = ~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir = ~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file = ~/.mutt/certificates

set move = no

set certificate_file =~/.mutt/certificates

set smtp_authenticators = 'gssapi:login'

set sort = "reverse-date-received"
set editor='vim "+normal \\ec" +/^$/'
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved.

I had to change the smtp_url, I had to put the full mail address not just the username. So it'd be:

```
set smtp_url = "smtp://user.name@aol.com@smtp.aol.com:587"
```